# Why is my C program to replaces tabs with the right amount of spaces not working when I enter 2 or more consecutive tabs

Tags: c

If I enter one tab the spacing is correct so why is it giving less spaces when I enter consecutive tabs between text?

```
/**********************************************************
 * Replaces TABs with an appropriate number of spaces *
 *                                                                                                  *
 **********************************************************/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
        int ch;
    int i=0;
    while((ch=getchar()) !=EOF)
    {
        if(ch=='\t')
        {
            for(i=0;i<4;i++)
                putchar(' ');
        }
        else
                putchar(ch);
    }
    return 0;
}
 ![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyA10.jpg)
```

Comment: Show the exact input and output that you supply  , the code looks OK from here. Maybe you are mistaken about what the output actually is

Comment: You will replace each `'\t'` with `4-spaces`, but you may have existing `spaces` next to your `'\t'` that makes it look like your replacement `space` count is off. It's either `'\t'` which is replaced, or it's not, so your code looks right in that sense.

Comment: Your program works for me exactly as it seems it should.  The input is echoed to the output, with each tab character converted to four space characters.  Including when multiple tabs are adjacent to each other in the input.

Comment: Yes, Your code is works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expand with spaces to the next tab stop, it would be better.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ch;
    int i=0,col=0;

    while((ch=getchar()) !=EOF) {
        if(ch=='\t') {
            for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
                putchar(' ');
                col++;
                if((col%4)==0) break;
            }
        }
        else {
            putchar(ch);
            if(ch=='\n' || ch=='\r') col=0;
            else col++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program works fine.

Most likely (like on my system), tabs are represented larger than 4 spaces on your console (on mine, tabs are 8 spaces large). In such a case, your output can appear shorter than your input:

```
->      leading tab, as large as 8 spaces
....converted to four spaces
```

Sure, this will not apply always, as tabs have fixed positions (first line shows where a tab will place the subsequent characters):

```
********++++++++********+++++++
hello-> world
hello....world (not shortened this time)

********++++++++********+++++++
hello-> ->      world (consecutive tabs again)
hello........world
```